# Problema con arreglo char en estructura

Tags: array, c, estructuras-de-datos

creo que me acabo de topar con mi primer error fatal en programacion, no tengo mucha idea respecto a ello, soy nuevo en esto.
El error inicia en el primer for, ya lo probé, después de tener la productos[i].nombre y mostrarlo, osea ----Producto 1 Chicles---Por dar un ejemplo, despues de eso los chicles dejan de funcionar, se quedan vacios ese slot del arreglo, lo se por que puse printf("%s",productos[i].nombre) y me aparecia vacio, ojo todo esto despues de la primera captura de meses (despues de julio, antes de julio o en medio del printf y el scan funciona esto)
Adjunto codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    struct producto{
        char  nombre[];
        float julio;
        float agosto;
        float septiembre;
        float octubre;
        float noviembre;
        float diciembre;
    }productos[4];
float integralmeses(float*,float*,float*,float*,float*,float*);
float integralprod(float*);
float promedio(float);
float mayor(float[]);
int main ()
{
    int i,n;
    float *mes1,*mes2,*mes3,*mes4,*mes5,*mes6,suma[4],total,*pintegral,prom,masgrande;
strcpy(productos[0].nombre, "Chicles"); 
strcpy(productos[1].nombre, "Chiclosos"); 
strcpy(productos[2].nombre, "Gomitas");
strcpy(productos[3].nombre, "Paletas");
printf("Bienvenido....\n");
printf("Favor de ingresar las cantidad que genero cada mes del segundo semestre\n");
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("\t-----Producto %d ""%s""-----\n",i+1,productos[i].nombre);
    fflush (stdin);
    printf("Julio: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].julio);
    mes1 = &productos[i].julio; 
    printf("Agosto: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].agosto);
    mes2 = &productos[i].agosto;
    printf("Septiembre: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].septiembre);
    mes3 = &productos[i].septiembre;
    printf("Octubre: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].octubre);
    mes4 = &productos[i].octubre;
    printf("Noviembre: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].noviembre);
    mes5 = &productos[i].noviembre;
    printf("Diciembre: ");scanf("%f",&productos[i].diciembre);
    mes6 = &productos[i].diciembre;
    suma[i]=integralmeses(mes1,mes2,mes3,mes4,mes5,mes6);
    pintegral = &suma[i];
    total += integralprod(pintegral);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

prom = promedio(total);
masgrande = mayor(suma);
printf("Producto      \tNombre        \tJulio    \t Agosto  \tSeptiembre   \tOctubre \t Noviembre  \tDiciembre  \tTotal\n");
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    printf("%7d",i+1);
    printf("%s",productos[i].nombre);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].julio);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].agosto);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].septiembre);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].octubre);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].noviembre);
    printf("\t%7.2f ",productos[i].diciembre);
    printf("\t%10.2f \n",suma[i]);
}

printf("\n\nSuma total de los 4 es: %.2f\nPromedio es: %.2f\n",total,prom);
printf("El producto mas alto fue el numero %.f\n",1+masgrande);

system("pause");

return 0;
}
float promedio(float total)
{
    float promedio;
    promedio = total / 4 ;
    return promedio;
}
float integralprod(float* n)
{
    float integralprod;
        integralprod = (*n);
    return integralprod;
}
float integralmeses(float* julio, float* agosto, float* septiembre, float* octubre, float* noviembre, float* diciembre)
{
    float sumatoria;
        sumatoria = (*julio)+(*agosto)+(*septiembre)+(*octubre)+(*noviembre)+(*diciembre);
    return sumatoria;
    
}
float mayor(float n[4])
{
    float mayor=0,posmayor=0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(n[i] > mayor)
        {
            mayor = n[i];
            posmayor = i;
        }
    }
    return posmayor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Me podrías decir qué tamaño tiene este array?

```
char  nombre[];
```

Es un detalle importante porque C no verifica si escribes fuera de los límites del array, luego si en un array metes más elementos de los que entran en realidad, empezarás a pisar memoria de otras variables y el programa se volverá errático.

Tienes que darle un tamaño al array:

```
char nombre[10];
```

El 10 no está elegido al azar, `"Chiclosos"` es la cadena más larga y `strlen("Chiclosos")==9`, si le sumamos un espacio para el finalizador de cadena tenemos el ya famoso `10`.

Comment: Gracias ya funciono a la perfección, no tome en cuenta eso, me enfoque tanto en que el problema era en otro lado que olvido lo básico